# Django urldispatcher: directing the request to special view

Tags: django, django-urls

**Django=3.0.8**

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('<slug:categories>/', include('categories.urls', namespace="categories")),
]
```

**categories/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CategoryGeneralView.as_view(), name='general'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<type>novosti|tema)$/',CategorySpecialView.as_view(), name="type"),
    path('draft/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="draft_post_detail"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
]
```

**Problem**

When I input either of

1. http://localhost:8000/windows/tema/
2. http://localhost:8000/windows/novosti/

the request goes to PostDetailView. But I want it to go to CategorySpecialView.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use 2 separate paths, i.e.:

```
path('novosti/', CategorySpecialView.as_view(), name = 'type'),
path('tema/', CategorySpecialView.as_view(), name = 'type'),
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this doesn't seem to help me. Your names coincide. Even if they are differrent, it won't help. As I don't want to catch such differences wherever I use this url.